# Capture output of all recursion calls during multiple recursion calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : list of integers
    # @return a list of list of integers

    def check(self,arr,l,i):
        for j in range(l,i):
            if arr[j]==arr[i]:
                return 0
        return 1
    def calc(self,arr,l,r,temp):
        if l>=r:
            #return arr
            self.result.append(temp)
            print(temp)
        #print(arr)
        for i in range(l,r):
            if self.check(arr,l,i):
                arr[l],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[l]
                temp=arr
                self.calc(arr,l+1,r,temp)
                arr[l],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[l]
    def permute(self, A):
        self.result=[]
        temp=[]
        self.calc(A,0,len(A),temp)
        print(self.result)
```

Input:

```
 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Above code is based on this problem from geeksforgeeks(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/) .I am trying to store all possible distinct permutations for a particular seuqenece like 1,2,3. I am not able to capture the output of recursion calls in self.result ([1,2,3] is repeating when i try to do it) variable but i am able to print it correctly. Could some one help how to store it in self.result variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because at every recursion level you are modifying the same list. When you do `tmp = arr` both `tmp` and `arr` refer to the same list object. Instead you need to copy the list via `tmp = arr.copy()` in order to capture the current state (and to be not affected by changes made in the recursion).